# Define a function that calculates the partial derivative of another function

Tags: python, function, sympy, partial, derivative

I have learned how to automatically find the partial derivative of a function with sympy. My problem is, I need to define a new function that returns the partial derivative of the other function.

```
from sympy import Symbol, Derivative

y= Symbol('y')

function = y ** 2

deriv = Derivative(function, y).doit()

def func(y):
    return deriv
```

Something like that. Hope you all understood. Thanks!

Comment: The variable "deriv" isn't supposed to be there. The "Derivative(function, y).doit()" is supposed to replace the "return" statement in func().

Answer (score 0):

So `y` is another function as in predefined like `y = Symbol('x') ** 2`? I believe your function need another input.

```
x = Symbol('x')
y = x ** 2

def func(function, symbol):
    deriv = Derivative(function, symbol).doit() 
    return deriv

derivative = func(y, x)
```

You can't do it without specifying symbol - especially since this is partial derivative you need to tell which symbol it's trying to derive against.